# UDP Multicast not receiving message

Tags: c, sockets, udp, multicast

I am trying to make a simple UDP multicast example where a message is sent from one program and received from the other but right now the output is only:

```
Connected
Message Sent
```

and

```
bind
setup multicast
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing so that I can receive the message successfully? Thank you!! Here are the codes in full:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int udp_socket_info;
struct sockaddr_in udp_server;
char* message="test";

    //create socket
    udp_socket_info = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udp_socket_info == -1) {
    puts("Could not create socket");
    }

//assign local values
    udp_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("225.0.0.37"); //multicast address
    udp_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    udp_server.sin_port = htons( 1100 );

    //checks connection 
    if (connect(udp_socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&udp_server, sizeof(udp_server)) < 0) {
    perror("Connection error");
    }
    puts("Connected");

    //sends message
    if( sendto(udp_socket_info , message , strlen(message) , 0, (struct sockaddr *)&udp_server, sizeof(udp_server)) < 0) {     
perror("Send failed");
    }
    puts("Message Sent");

}
```

and the second program is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

//initialize udp socket and structures
int udp_socket_info;
struct sockaddr_in udp_server;
struct sockaddr addr;
struct ip_mreq mreq;
socklen_t fromlen;
fromlen = sizeof addr;
char incoming_message[100];

    //create udp socket
    udp_socket_info = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udp_socket_info == -1) {
    puts("Could not create socket");
        }

    // set up 
memset((char*)&udp_server,0,sizeof(udp_server));
    udp_server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    udp_server.sin_port = htons( 1100 );
udp_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.100"); //local address

    // bind 
    if (bind(udp_socket_info,(struct sockaddr *)&udp_server, sizeof(udp_server)) < 0) {
  perror("bind error");
  exit (1);
      }
puts("bind");

 // use setsockopt() to join multicast group
 mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr=inet_addr("225.0.0.37"); //multicast address
 mreq.imr_interface.s_addr= htonl(INADDR_ANY); //can use local address here too
 if (setsockopt(udp_socket_info, IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
  perror("setsockopt");
  exit (1);
      }
puts("setup multicast");

    //Receive an incoming message
    if( recvfrom(udp_socket_info, incoming_message , sizeof(incoming_message), 0, &addr, &fromlen) < 0) {
puts("Received failed");
exit (1);
    }
    puts("Message received");
    puts(incoming_message);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a network sniffing program, such as Wireshark, to verify that the sending program is correctly sending the packet?

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the receiving socket to INADDR_ANY, not a local interface address. Otherwise you run the risk that the sender is out there via a different route and can't reach your socket. On some platforms you can bind it to the multicast address itself.

NB when you get an error it isn't sufficient to print a message of your own devising. The message must contain the `errno`, or the result of `strerror()`. For example, call `perror()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your receiver should not bind to a local address.  It should instead bind to either `INADDR_ANY` or the multicast address you intend on joining.  Binding to a local address breaks multicast on Linux systems.

Note that if you bind to a multicast address, this means you'll only receive packets for that multicast address.  If you want to receive from multiple multicast addresses or if you also want to receive unicast packets then you need to bind to `INADDR_ANY`.

When joining a multicast group, using INADDR_ANY causes you to join the specified group on the default network interface.  It's generally a good idea to explicitly specify an interface.

As EJP mentioned, you should always use perror to print error messages from any system or library call to ensure that a meaningful error message is printed.

Wireshark is an important tool for programs such as this.  It helps you ensure that packets are going out and coming in the network interfaces you expect.

Also, if the sender and receive are on different network segments, you'll need to set the TTL via the IP_MULTICAST_TTL socket option.  You also need to make sure that any routers between them are configured to pass multicast traffic.

Comment: VG. Does it really break multicast? I would have thought that as long as you use the same IP address for binding and joining, and the sender is out there on that route, it should work. But I haven't touched a Linux system for years.

Comment: @EJP It does indeed.  I had a Windows user of [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) request binding to a specific address, so I added that feature.  It worked fine for him, but the next day I got complaints from Linux users, so I had to revert the change.

Comment: @EJP: You are right - it doesn't. My ubuntu perfectly receive multicast on the socket bound to multicast IP/port. The story gets grim with connect(). Say, if you like send and receive multicast packets on the same socket you can't use connect() to set dst multicast addr as it will stop you from receiving since a packet received on a connected socket must have src addr = connected addr, and it will never be the case with multicast.

Comment: @EJP Binding to a multicast address actually is fine.  It's when you bind to a local address that Linux has a problem with.  I've edited to clarify the difference.